# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseXML' of undefined

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm attempting to develop an website using JavaScript,

The goal, is to get data of a xml file, and convert them into vars.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        initMap(this);
    }
};

xhttp.open("GET", "https://applications002.brest-metropole.fr/WIPOD01/Transport/REST/getGeolocatedVehiclesPosition?format=xml&route_id=1&trip_headsign=Fort%20Montbarey", true);

xhttp.send();

function initMap(xml) {
    var xlat, xlon, i, xmlDoc;
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    xlat = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Lat');
    xlon = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Lon');
    /*
    xlat = xml.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('lat');
    xlon = xml.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('lon');
    */
    for (i = 0; i < xlat.length; i++) {
        var latcode = xlat[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var loncode = xlon[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        //var myLatLng = "{lat: " + latcode + ", lng: " + loncode +"}";
        //var myLatLng = {lat: latcode, lng: loncode};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(latcode, loncode),
            map: map,
        });
    }
    [...]
}
```

but I obtain this code error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseXML' of undefined` @ -> `xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;`

I've already tried to remplace `xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;` by `xmlDoc = this.responseXML;`

but I obtain the some error for getElementByTagName: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined`

Thanks for Help !
Jacques

EDIT: Code source: [Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iuyMgS0dmKUitKoRbUJZ6-LRVaACjOIL_qnXwBJ_8-Y/edit?usp=sharing) Yes the live demo works for me, I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Here [is a live demo](https://phihag.de/2018/so/xhr.html) that shows it works as well. Does the live demo work for you? If so, the problem is in the code you have not shown us. Otherwise: Which webbrowser are you using?

Comment: guess the next question is, which browser?

Comment: Code source: [Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iuyMgS0dmKUitKoRbUJZ6-LRVaACjOIL_qnXwBJ_8-Y/edit?usp=sharing)
Yes the live demo works for me, I'm using Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

For the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined` error it is quite possible that one of the entries in the XML file does not have the Tag Value you are looking for defined. Scan through the xml and make sure there is a value for that tag in each entry.

I don't know how to deal with a document that isn't complete.

As to the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseXML'` I get that on a lot of pages that seem to work absolutely fine. To the point where I ignore it now; but I would love for someone to explain it so that I can solve whatever the underlying issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Its beacause yout did not  given child node name at  `xlat[i]` and  `xlon[i]`.

change this in to

`/*var latcode = xlat[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue; var loncode = xlon[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;*/`

to

```
/*
var latcode = xlat[i].getElementsByTagName("give child node tag name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

 var loncode = xlon[i].getElementsByTagName("give child node tag name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
*/
```